# Cocoa Async Socket Tutorial Code Conversion from Swift 2 to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, swift2, bonjour, code-conversion

I am working through a Swift 2 Cocoa Async Socket tutorial which was downloaded from https://github.com/nickyhuyskens/SwiftCocoaAsyncSocketTutorial  It was written in Swift 2 and I am working with Xcode 8 / Swift 3.  The conversion seem fairly good with only a few correction except for one place where I cannot seem to make the needed correction.

Original Swift 2 code:

```
func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket!, didRead data: Data!, withTag tag: Int)
 {
    if tag == 1 {
         var bodyLength: Int16 = 0
         data.getBytes(&bodyLength, length: sizeof(Int16))
         print("Header received with bodylength: \(bodyLength)")
         socket.readDataToLength(UInt(bodyLength), withTimeout: -1, tag: 2)
    } else if tag == 2 {             
         let packet = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! Packet
         PacketHandler.HandlePacket(packet)
         socket.readDataToLength(UInt(sizeof(Int16)), withTimeout: -1, tag: 1)
        socket.readData(toLength: UInt(MemoryLayout<Int16>.size), withTimeout: -1, tag: 1)
    }
}
```

My Swift 3 changes:

```
func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket!, didRead data: Data!, withTag tag: Int) {
   if tag == 1 {
                    var bodyLength: UInt16 = 0
        bodyLength = (UInt16(MemoryLayout<Data>.size))
        print("Header received with bodylength: \(bodyLength)")
        socket.readData(toLength: UInt(bodyLength), withTimeout: -1, tag: 2)
    } else if tag == 2 {
        let packet = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! Packet
        PacketHandler.HandlePacket(packet)
        socket.readData(toLength: UInt(MemoryLayout<Int16>.size), withTimeout: -1, tag: 1)
    }
}
```

When it gets to the line

```
let packet = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! Packet
```

the result is a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  I have been looking at posts involving the changes in Swift 3 around change to getting the "sizeof" data and am not sure if the change to "MemoryLayout" was correct.  Also I have tried a number of changes following posts involving Swift 3 changes to the use of the NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData functionality but those also do not provide a working solution.

Any assistance or pointing to where the conversion solution can be found would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, please, please stop using `!` to force unwrap objects. This error is being caused because you're force unwrapping objects and not properly handling the fact those objects could be `nil`. Your objects should either be optional or nonnull. You will continue to run into crashes like this if you continue to use `!`. It's not safe code.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(MemoryLayout<Data>.size == 8)
```

prints

```
true
```

Are You sure that this is what do You expect? It is the size of Data type, not the number of stored bytes.

the size of data (for example)

```
let data = Data(bytes: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
print(data.count)
```

prints

```
10
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I am definitely looking for the number of stored bytes in the second part of the socket data packet.  This data packet must then be 'unpackaged' in the tag == 2 segment where it is using the "NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data)" process to restore the original object.  There seems to have been a significant change in how this is handled in Swift 3 and even after doing a fair bit of research and reading, I am not totally clear on how to have Swift 3 handle this properly.  Thanks in advance in help with this.